# Looking to automatically generate bibliography-appropriate metadata from YouTube URL

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, bibliography

I need to cite a hundred or so YouTube videos in a specific format, and would like to generate these citations automatically using just the video URLs.

I know there are existing websites that can do this (for example, [Scribbr](https://www.scribbr.com/apa-citation-generator/new/video/?data=N4Igxg9gdgLghgSygUwE4BUEwDbJALhAE0IBXdUgIzwF8g&notice=notices.youTube)), but for efficiency, I would need the output in a format that varies from what is offered.

I have some rudimentary HTML and Javascript ability, and feel I could piece this together if I had a method of obtaining the title of a video, the name of the uploader, and the date of publication (Month DD, YYYY) as strings. However, I don't know how to do this.

I've looked into taking the data from https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=urlgoeshere&format=json, but that doesn't seem to include the date, and I'm not sure how to even obtain the title from that.

This is perhaps too vague of a question, but do you have any suggestions for where to begin with this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I had a method of obtaining the *title of a video*, the *name of the
> uploader*, and the *date of publication (Month DD, YYYY)* as strings.

In order to get these values, you could follow these steps:

1. With your first request (*i.e: https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=urlgoeshere&format=json*), extract the name of the channel:

Example:

> URL:
> `https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EHSlhnE6Ck&format=json`

Results - *formatted for clarity*:

```
{
    "title": "Understanding Digital Tracking",
    "author_name": "GCFLearnFree.org",
    "author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/gcflearnfree",
    "type": "video",
    "height": 113,
    "width": 200,
    "version": "1.0",
    "provider_name": "YouTube",
    "provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
    "thumbnail_height": 360,
    "thumbnail_width": 480,
    "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6EHSlhnE6Ck/hqdefault.jpg",
    "html": "\u003ciframe width=\u0022200\u0022 height=\u0022113\u0022 src=\u0022https://www.youtube.com/embed/6EHSlhnE6Ck?feature=oembed\u0022 frameborder=\u00220\u0022 allow=\u0022accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\u0022 allowfullscreen\u003e\u003c/iframe\u003e"
}
```

2. Extract the name of the user - by reading the "`author_url`" value:

> "author_url":"https://www.youtube.com/user/gcflearnfree"

3. Use this request for get the title, name of the uploader and the date of publication of the videos:

URL: `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=<name_of_the_user>` - replace `<name_of_the_user>` with the name obtained in step 2.

Example: `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=gcflearnfree`

4. Make the request using the URL shown in the step 3 - you'll get these results:

---

Example:

```
<feed
    xmlns:yt="http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015"
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <link rel="self" href="http://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=gcflearnfree"/>
    <id>yt:channel:UCeYUHG6o0YguM-g23htdsSw</id> 
    <yt:channelId>UCeYUHG6o0YguM-g23htdsSw</yt:channelId> <-- Use channel_id instead.
    <title>GCFLearnFree.org</title> 
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeYUHG6o0YguM-g23htdsSw"/>
    <author>
        <name>GCFLearnFree.org</name> <-- Name of the publisher
        <uri>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeYUHG6o0YguM-g23htdsSw</uri>
    </author>
    <published>2007-02-27T15:22:42+00:00</published><-- Publication date
    <entry>
        <id>yt:video:xKuJrmlCdig</id>
        <yt:videoId>xKuJrmlCdig</yt:videoId>
        <yt:channelId>UCeYUHG6o0YguM-g23htdsSw</yt:channelId>
        <title>What is HTML?</title><-- Title of the video
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKuJrmlCdig"/>
        <author>
            <name>GCFLearnFree.org</name>
            <uri>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeYUHG6o0YguM-g23htdsSw</uri>
        </author>
        <published>2021-05-04T17:29:00+00:00</published>
        <updated>2021-05-05T06:31:50+00:00</updated>
        <media:group>
            <media:title>What is HTML?</media:title>
            <media:content url="https://www.youtube.com/v/xKuJrmlCdig?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="390"/>
            <media:thumbnail url="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/xKuJrmlCdig/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>
            <media:description>In this video, you’ll learn about HTML and how it is used to code webpages. We hope you enjoy! To learn more, check out our Basic HTML tutorial here: https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/basic-html/ #whatishtml #htmlcode #learnhtml</media:description>
            <media:community>
                <media:starRating count="100" average="4.80" min="1" max="5"/>
                <media:statistics views="1571"/>
            </media:community>
        </media:group>
    </entry>
    [More entries goes here...] 
</feed>
```

From the previous results you can read the *title of a video*, the *name of the uploader*, and the *date of publication (Month DD, YYYY)*.